# SELECT element's arrow invisible in IE8 until mouseover

Tags: select, internet-explorer-8, mouseover, invisible

Curious as to why the arrow used to initiate showing option listitems of a SELECT control is invisible until I mouseover in IE8. I am able to fix the problem by turning on Compatibility View, but would like to know the answer if anyone has suggestion.

All of the javascript associated works fine and the events fire, just not sure what anomaly is causing the actual SELECT arrow to be invisible until the element is hovered.

There are no styles set for the controls itself (such as display: block; etc...)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.

It seems as though if you set a min-width on the select element the arrows have problems re-drawing.

My solution was to set the min-width on selects back to 0 for IE8 only.